# How can I make an id column in MYSQL which has auto increment using python?

Tags: python, mysql, centos

I am using Python in CentOS and I`m doing a simple code to link python to MYSQL. My problem is I want to auto increment the id column. I use CentOS terminal .

I tried to write this so the program increments id column automatically because I saw it in some answer

---

```
   record = [12,'tom']
   cursor.execute("insert into t3(number,sent)values(%s,%s),record)
```

---

it give me the ERROR

```
   <module> cursor.execute("insert into t3(number,sent)values(%s,%s)",record)
    NameError :name 'cursor' is not defined
```

So guys please it`s my first experience  in stack overflow I hope to find good answer. :(

Answer (score 0):

Read the error. Have you defined a cursor variable?

Assuming you're using the mysql module, once you create your database object you can use it to create a cursor.

```
import mysql.connector

database = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="username", passwd="password", database="nameofdatabase")

cursor = database.cursor()

record = [12,'tom']

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO t3(number,sent) VALUES(%s,%s)", record)
```

Hope I could help, but if not try being more specific. Maybe posting all of your code?